# Why does SSL architecture have two distinct functions?

Tags: ssl, public-key-encryption

On a high level, it seems to me that SSL has two distinct functions:

1. To bind a domain name to a specific organization
2. To send out a public key for encryption

These functions seem very different to me. What is missing from my understanding of the model?

Update for clarity: I base my question on findings from searches. For example, one source says, “SSL Certificates bind together: A domain name, server name or hostname. An organizational identity (i.e. company name) and location.” And, other sources discuss encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL has none of the functions to describe. What you describe are only parts of how the actual functionality is achieved. The real function of SSL is to protect the data in transit.

The certificate with subject and key is needed within this function (at least) to authenticate the server in order to make sure that the client talks to the expected server and not to some man in the middle. This is achieved by making sure that a) the certificate is issued by a trusted party (the certificate authority) and that it is issued to the expected domain, i.e. the same one which is included in the visited URL.

Note that SSL does not make any claims about how trustworthy the site or the party behind the certificate is. It also does not make any claims if the organization you expect is really the one which owns the visited domain. The latter part is done by the certificate authority for some kind of certificates, i.e. the EV certificates. But for most certificates it is only checked that the current owner of the domain requested the certificate and not who the owner actually is.

Comment: I am finding your last statement confusing. How can it check that the current owner requested the certificate if it can't identify who the owner actually is? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins: it is called domain validation. For example the CA can ask the owner to put specific information at a specific URL at the domains web site and it is assumed that only the (current) owner of the domain can do this. Thus it will not verify who the owner actually is but only that the claimed owner can do specific things. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-validated_certificate) for more information.

Comment: I find that this statement adds significant clarity in answering the question, "The real function of SSL is to protect the data in transit."